# Does the U.S. monitor who is on foreign flights?

Tags: air-travel, us-citizens, security

I am a US citizen. If I fly out of Mexico to Argentina, will the US government know where I am?

Comment: Unlikely, and not through any legal means, although who knows if NSA get involved. The US do monitor who overflies their airspace though (by requiring carriers to provide the manifest in advance) and they have been known to order planes to divert in order to effect the arrest of a wanted person.

Comment: @Calchas: Are you answering the (general) question in the title or the (specific) one in the body? At least in the former case, "not through any legal means" is not necessarily true, given that [agreements such as the one between the U.S. and the EU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States%E2%80%93European_Union_Agreement_on_Passenger_Name_Records) exist.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I try, although not always successfully, to answer the question which is asked rather than the summary in the title. :) In any respect that treaty only covers flights between the EU and the US, not PNRs which don't touch the US. I was not able to find a similiar treaty concluded between Mexico and the US and I would doubt that one exists between Argentina and the US.

Comment: If governments really want to know, they'd probably be able to find out even if you walk or canoe to Argentina. Chances are that they don't care at all though.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that US officials would be advised either by Mexican officials of your departure or Argentinian officials of your arrival. As a US citizen,  you don't need a visa to enter Argentina, although changes earlier this year to the Argentinian immigration laws may subject all arriving passengers to new, and added, scrutiny. Its Customs and Immigration officials now access both the Advanced Passenger Information (API) and the INTERPOL Criminal Information System databases as part of the country's improved border security measures.